# How to remove leading and trailing spaces from strings in a Python list

Tags: python

i have a list:

```
row=['hi', 'there', 'how', ...........'some stuff is here are ','you']
```

as you can see `row[8]='some stuff is here are '`

if the last character is a space i would like to get everything except for the last character like this:

```
if row[8][len(row[8])-1]==' ':
  row[8]=row[8][0:len(row[8])-2]
```

this method is not working. can someone suggest a better syntax please?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What error do you get?

Comment: Actually, I cannot see that `row[8]` is `'some stuff is here'` - you omitted that part. If it were, the code you had, while not the most Pythonic, would have worked.

Comment: @Thanatos can you please suggest how i can make it more pythonic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
row = [x.strip() for x in row]
```

(if you just want to get spaces at the end, use `rstrip`)

Comment: This also gets rid of leading spaces. The OP might not want that. See `rstrip()`.

Answer (score 4):

Negative indexes count from the end. And slices are anchored before the index given.

```
if row[8][-1]==' ':
  row[8]=row[8][:-1]
```

Comment: on the first line: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong. Like not checking to see if the length is greater than 0.

Comment: @user2982349-this-is-a-terrible-name: Are you sure row[8] isn't ''?

Answer (score 4):

So you want it without trailing spaces? Can you just use `row[8].rstrip`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `row[8].rstrip()`?

Comment: @MAK: You're right of course. I was being lazy and just giving the method name ;)